# Cookies in Set-Cookie are being ignored by browser

Tags: c#, http, cookies, azure-functions, blazor

I do have a problem with setting cookies. I'm running a small application on Azure Functions and a static webpage as frontend, and on the login request my function properly returns a cookie in the response. Here is the whole set of response headers coming from my Azure function.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 11 Oct 2020 20:40:16 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Content-Length: 180
Set-Cookie: RefreshToken=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJVc2VyTmFtZSI6IlNvc3NlbmJpbmRlciIsImV4cCI6IjYzNzM4MDQ2NTE3MTM3NjE4NCJ9.CCv3a41iPut4eC9jK2eqAzOLP5tWLjMlRgduSkUpS40; expires=Mon, 11 Oct 2021 20:40:17 GMT; path=/; samesite=lax
Set-Cookie: Test=Val; path=/
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Set-Cookie
```

As you can see, I included my proper token, as well as just a small test cookie, just to verify whether it would even work with a very simple cookie. Hint, it doesn't.

Here is my request:

[image]

Sadly, whatever I try, chrome and e.g. firefox completely ignore my cookies. I didn't yet manage to have a single cookie set, no matter what I try.

I tried it on localhost as well as a *.web.core.windows.net static website now, but I just can't get it to work.

I think my backend is not the culprit, as the response headers seem to be set properly. But something just isn't quite right. I have read up on a lot of threads now mentioning what should be set and what not, I've probably tried them all now. Whether it is the secure flag, the samesite flag, whatever.

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I added a minimal reproducible example at http://www.filedropper.com/cookieproblem

To run:

1. Navigate to the "CookieProblem" folder containing the CookieProblem.csproj. Open up cmd and run it with "func start" (requires Azure Functions CLI tool)
2. Now, run the BlazorApp1 in VS. Open the page and keep dev tools open. On load, it should make a request to the locally running function called "Run" in the network tab.
3. It should now also not set a cookie for you.

Comment: How are you making the HTTP request for which the Set-Cookie header is the response? Clicking a link? Submitting a form? Using `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`? Something else? Also: Is it cross-origin?

Comment: @Quentin I added the request - It's a bit of an exotic setup, I'm using C# WebAssembly, so it's C# HttpClient essentially. Not sure what it is being translated to. And regarding the cross-origin: Locally no, but in production it is calling my Azure Function on a different domain, so cross origin there

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Quentin I added a compressed sln containing my problem

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, this problem has caused me SO much frustration. I was tinkering around in my minified solution for a while and added a basic website with the `fetch()` functionality, because I wanted to know whether this is due to Blazor.

So, with the `fetch()` code it is important to add the `credentials: 'include'` parameter. After doing this, everything worked.

Well, after that I spend a good share of time googling how to do this for C#'s `HttpClient`. The solution is to use an `HttpRequestMessage` and set `requestMessage.SetBrowserRequestCredentials(BrowserRequestCredentials.Include);`

Also, on server side you should make sure to configure your e.g. local.settings.json accordingly to have "CORS" and "CORSCredentials" set n the "Host" subsection of the Json (In my example this is for an Azure Function project, this might be different for you).

That's it. Now CORS cookies work. What a ride finding this one line of code...

EDIT:

Here's an example of my local.settings.json file:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    },
    "Host": {
        "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
        "CORS": "https://localhost:5001",
        "CORSCredentials": true
    }
}
```

Comment: _Also, you should configure your e.g. local.settings.json accordingly to hve "CORS" and "CORSCredentials" set accordingly in the "Host" subsection of the Json._

Can you tell me what do you mean by that?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow Sorry, this was probably a bit confusing. I was working with Azure Functions for the scope of this question, and for Azure Functions there's a configuration file where you can add allowed CORS origin URLs, and you can set CORSCredentials to true in the configuration.

Comment: What a pity my client is not server-side, but Angular app. Anyway, I've tried all the proposed changes regarding this stuff and still can't make my cookie be saved on AspNetCore 3.1 app side...

Comment: @Alexander If you're using fetch(), did you include the credentials: 'include' option?

Comment: @sossenbinder i've finally won :) don't know what exactly was the last step... but seems like removing `domain: null` (removing domain option at all)

Comment: Adding the package that contains those `HttpRequestMessage` extension methods and using them to include credentials also works on Uno Platform WASM projects, in case anyone comes across this answer when searching for that.

Comment: I can create an HttpRequestMessage object and set BrowserRequestCredentials.Include. But what do I have to do with that object afterwards? thx!

Comment: @JensMander You can send it with a regular HttpClient, I think the correct method was .SendAsync(message,... );

Comment: Sure, but SendAsync doesn't have any parameters to set BrowserRequestCredentials. I ended up calling ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(new MyHandler()) on the return value of builder.Services.AddHttpClient(...) in Program.cs and defined a class MyHandler: HttpClientHandler. There you can finally override SendAsync and set the BrowserRequestCredentials for the request. btw: According to Fiddler that doesn't modify request headers but leads to the browser accepting cookies sent with the response (vie Set-Cookie-Header). Very strange. greetings from HH